# iOS Chrome not respecting safe-area-inset for notch

Tags: css, ios, google-chrome, chrome-ios

I have an issue where a landscape version of Chrome is adding white space to the left and right of my screen.

[image: Example of iOS Chrome notches]

Here are the specs:

[image: Browser specs]

I have a "kitchen sink" approach where I've tried everything to remove these white bars and make the background fullscreen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

And the following CSS:

```
html{
  margin: env(safe-area-inset);
  padding: env(safe-area-inset);
}


html, body, img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  width: 120vw;

}

img{
  margin: env(safe-area-inset);
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Here is a live demo to play with:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/JjYygPg

I'm getting good results in **iOS Safari**, but it seems to stop there. Similar issues have been raised [env(safe-area-inset-top) not working on Android Pie + WebView 69](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476016/envsafe-area-inset-top-not-working-on-android-pie-webview-69)

I'm wondering if this is a Chrome iOS bug, or if my implementation is incorrect. It's worth noting that Safari *does* remove the whitespace when these properties are added.

Comment: Are you using the correct [Viewport meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56293045/746736)?

Comment: @Turnip yes I am, sorry I forgot to include that in the original post. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">`

Comment: Just jumping in here to say that I'm currently having the same problem. The viewport tag works fine on Safari but not Chrome (iPhone 11 Pro Max)

Comment: Ditto. Did anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: @Lucas I'm afraid not. I think the best thing to do would be report it as a bug. I did, but my report has since been closed with one spam answer. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/43657915?hl=en

Comment: did you find solution for this ? i have same problem

Comment: I also have the same problem :/

Comment: Same Here, seems that either the Chrome Team doesn't see it important, because Edge does work.

Comment: Has anyone found a solve for this? Still seems to be the case. iOS Safari works, iOS Chrome does not

Comment: @James I'm afraid not so far... although I did find another issue was caused by codepen's iframe styling, so it's worth testing it outside of there (I'm sure you are already)

Comment: I think that the env inset value work correctly, so if we can detect iOS Chrome and apply negative values it should solve the problem